# How is it that all the years have passed and the children of the corn still look the same age?

Tags: children-of-the-corn

I understand they are in a religious cult but after twelve years those children would have grown up so how is nothing happening to them when their age limit on one movie is no one over the age of 18 and the other movie its 19. Why are all the children still looking young when twelve years have passed since they killed all the adults? What happens when they grow over twelve and wouldn’t the preacher kid have grown up too?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Corn#Film.2C_TV_and_theatrical_adaptations